# Determining coefficients in generating functions?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

The question is to determine the coefficient of x^8 in G(x) = (10x-1)/((1-4x)(1-x)).

I'm not sure what to do here, I don't know how to expand this.

I figured the decomposition for this equation to be: (3/(x-1)) - (2/(4x-1)) but I'm not even sure where to go from there.

Any general answers are welcome.
If it's possible please explain your answer because I'm a little lost on the entire concept. Thank you.

Comment: Something is missing. The author of the answer below knows something that I do not (then again, that is not unusual).

Comment: Once you have found an answer, please do not delete the content nor the title as it goes against the community rules.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**

You properly established that $$\frac{10 x-1}{(1-4 x) (1-x)}=\frac{3}{x-1}-\frac{2}{4 x-1}=-\frac{3}{1-x}+\frac{2}{1-4 x}$$ Now, remember that $$\frac{1}{1-y}=\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}y^i$$ So replace $y$ by $x$ for the first term and $y$ by $4x$ for the second term and combine the results.